# How to train a neural network in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm loading a neural network using tensorflow and colab notbook from google. I removed the fully connected layer of the output layer and added another fully connected with only one neuron, and I freezed the other layer. I'm using tf.keras.application.MobileNetV2 and I'm using the mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs. I want to train just this added output layer but I'm getting an 'error'.

My code is the following:

```
_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs.zip', origin=_URL, extract=True)

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), 'cats_and_dogs_filtered')

train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')  # directory with our training cat pictures
train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')  # directory with our training dog pictures
validation_cats_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats')  # directory with our validation cat pictures
validation_dogs_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs')  # directory with our validation dog pictures


num_cats_tr = len(os.listdir(train_cats_dir))
num_dogs_tr = len(os.listdir(train_dogs_dir))

num_cats_val = len(os.listdir(validation_cats_dir))
num_dogs_val = len(os.listdir(validation_dogs_dir))

total_train = num_cats_tr + num_dogs_tr
total_val = num_cats_val + num_dogs_val

print('total training cat images:', num_cats_tr)
print('total training dog images:', num_dogs_tr)

print('total validation cat images:', num_cats_val)
print('total validation dog images:', num_dogs_val)
print("--")
print("Total training images:", total_train)
print("Total validation images:", total_val)


batch_size = 32
epochs = 15
IMG_HEIGHT = 160
IMG_WIDTH = 160

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our training data
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our validation data

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='binary')




val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=validation_dir,
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                              class_mode='binary')

sample_training_images, _ = next(train_data_gen)


# This function will plot images in the form of a grid with 1 row and 5 columns where images are placed in each column.
def plotImages(images_arr):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(20,20))
    axes = axes.flatten()
    for img, ax in zip( images_arr, axes):
        ax.imshow(img)
        ax.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()



plotImages(sample_training_images[:5])

## Create the model
model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3), alpha=1.0, include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None , pooling='max', classes=2)
model.summary()
penultimate_layer = model.layers[-2]  # layer that you want to connect your new FC layer to 
new_top_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(penultimate_layer.output) # create new FC layer and connect it to the rest of the model
new_new_top_layer = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)(new_top_layer)
new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=new_new_top_layer)  # define your new model
new_model.summary()


for layer in new_model.layers[:-2]:
    layer.trainable = False
new_model.layers[-1].trainable = True
```

To training:

```
new_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I'm getting trouble with this part of the code

```
history = new_model.fit_generator(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch = total_train // batch_size,
    epochs = epochs,
    validation_data = val_data_gen,
    validation_steps = total_val // batch_size
)
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
Epoch 1/15

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-38-55517a65f99f> in <module>()
      4     epochs = epochs,
      5     validation_data = val_data_gen,
----> 6     validation_steps = total_val // batch_size
      7 )

5 frames

/tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in check_loss_and_target_compatibility(targets, loss_fns, output_shapes)
    741           raise ValueError('A target array with shape ' + str(y.shape) +
    742                            ' was passed for an output of shape ' + str(shape) +
--> 743                            ' while using as loss `' + loss_name + '`. '
    744                            'This loss expects targets to have the same shape '
    745                            'as the output.')

ValueError: A target array with shape (32, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 2, 2, 1) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

And I have to configure the network this way:

```
batch_size = 32
epochs = 15
IMG_HEIGHT = 160
IMG_WIDTH = 160
```

thanks

Comment: You have to add a flatten layer before the dense, so the output of your pretrained network is 2D and not 4D.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the last Dense layer; you have a layer with 2 neurons for the output but considering this is a binary classification using binary_crossentropy it should be `Dense(1)`.
From the error you can see the generator is creating a target array of shape `(batch_size, output_size)`. It is also worth using `new_model.summary()` to better understand the input/output shapes of each layer and the training parameters.

## EDIT:

As per @matias-valdenegro you also need to add a `Flatten()` layer before the `Dense(1)` for this to work properly as it seems to have an issue with the dimensions.

Comment: I've changed the last layer for 1 neuron but it didnt work either. And the `batch_size` has to be 32

Comment: I've already added added a `Flatten()` but didnt work too.
`model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3), alpha=1.0, include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None , pooling='max', classes=2)`
`penultimate_layer = model.layers[-2]  # layer that you want to connect your new FC layer to `
`new_top_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten() # create new FC layer and connect it to the rest of the model`
`new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(model.input, new_top_layer)  # define your new model`

Comment: I guess I have to add a maxpooling layer but I dont know  how to do it.

Comment: I cannot tell if the comments are distorting your code, but it looks like your flatten and dense(1) layers are not connected properly: `model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3), alpha=1.0, include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None , pooling='max', classes=2); new_top_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten() (model.output); output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(new_top_layer)` is this what you have implemented?

Comment: Yes thats what I got

Comment: can you add an edit with the new code under your existing question? I genuinely do not see the issue at the moment, so it might be helpful for others who see the question

Comment: Edited... I've changed the question, and the part of `Create the model` and the error... that is shown in the question